# ng-options with object not rendering key and value

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate a dropdown menu with a key and value pair from an array. I thought this would be easy but for some reason my dropdown always shows [Object, Object].

I have the following array

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.widget.suggestion = [
                { 'Department': 'Afdeling' },
                { 'JobTitle': 'Functie' },
                { 'OfficeNumber': 'Locatie' }
            ];
```

which I render in the following code:

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="widget.propertyInput" id="widgetselectedGroupName" ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in widget.suggestion"></select>
```

I would expect that it would produce:

```
 <option value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
```

but somehow I am doing somethign wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: wow that's a lot of properties

Comment: ng-options="(k, v) in widget.suggestion"